# Backbone+get from view

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something here but I'm attempting to pull a param from the URL, do a lookup using the value and use the model in a jade template for display. Simple enough, right?

So here's the thing: 
1. I have a View called Salutation. 
2. I have a model called Salutation. 
3. In the router workspace I have a function for salutation. 
4. I have a jade template that gets hit when the following URL is hit:

http://:/user/salutation?s=

When I click on the salutation the request is getting routed properly. However, the lookup portion is not happening. I have calls to my function in a db.js file that *should* get the salutation object.

My question is: where should I be calling for the object based on the token?

Been driving my nuts.

Comment: Which version of Backbone are you using? Previous versions of Backbone didn't have great support for grabbing values off the querystring and you have to do it manually. The latest version has better support for querystrings and you may have better luck with it.

Comment: I'm all good grabbing the param out of URL.  That's all good. I'm to the point where I just need to do the look up from the view and I'd be good. Just don't see how. Clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you have a token and you need to look up data based on the token and send it to a view. Is that right?